# Index: if multiple matches are found, give me the most common one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a database of audience retention from Later that I am trying got use to find the best times to post as the database increases.

Currently I have this code getting me the best time to post each day by highest audience value:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$1000,MATCH(MAX(B2:B1000),B2:B1000,0))
```

[image: Image of Spreadsheet]

This is working great, but as the data increases I think I will run into issues. In particular, I think if multiple values appear (like 3 entries of 27) appear in a column, the code will find it, but maybe not grab the ideal time.

So I am looking for some help to take the code above, and add to it so if the highest value in column b has duplicates, see if those duplicate highest values having matching time stamp entries in column a and give me the most common duplicate time, otherwise just give me the time stamp that matches the first highest value.

So if there are 3 entries of 27 in column b, but two of them have the same time stamp (12pm) and the third is 8am in column a, give me the 12pm time stamp, otherwise give me whatever one is the best (as the original code does)

I hope that makes sense to everyone and thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula FILTER:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$A$1000,B2:B1000=MAX(B2:B1000)),MODE.SNGL(MATCH(FILTER($A$2:$A$1000,B2:B1000=MAX(B2:B1000)),FILTER($A$2:$A$1000,B2:B1000=MAX(B2:B1000)),0)))
```

---

If not then use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$1000,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,MAX($A$2:$A$1000))),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,MAX($A$2:$A$1000)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work!